# Convert PFGeoPoint to String Error

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am tying to save a PFGeoPoint in a parse server with the following code:

```
var coordinates = PFGeoPoint (latitude: (newCoordinate2.latitude), longitude:(newCoordinate2.longitude))

        var aboutSpot = PFObject(className: "spotdetail")

        aboutSpot["name"] = "name"
        aboutSpot [PFGeoPoint] = coordinates
        aboutSpot.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succes, error) -> Void in
            print("separate name and geopoint have been saved")
        }
```

and I get the following message:

```
swift cannot convert value of type `(PFGeoPoint).type (aka 'PFGeoPoint.type`) to expected argument type 'String'
```

What can I change so Xcode stops thinking that I am trying to save a String?

Comment: Pretty sure Xcode doesn't just *think* you're trying to save a string. You *are* trying to save a string. Can you print `aboutSpot["name"]` or does that throw an error too?

Comment: Thanks for helping out I just figured it out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out so I added a column manually in the parse server then changed the code like this and it now works, thanks for helping out

```
var coordinates = PFGeoPoint (latitude: (newCoordinate2.latitude), longitude:(newCoordinate2.longitude))

var aboutSpot = PFObject(className: "spotdetail")

aboutSpot["name"] = "replaceNow"
aboutSpot ["PFGeoPoint"] = coordinates
aboutSpot.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succes, error) -> Void in
    print("separate name and geopoint have been saved")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the longitude and latitude as `double` first and then use `distanceInKilometersTo` or `distanceInMilesTo`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping out I just figured it out .